# Draw line in xor mode

Tags: matplotlib

I'm trying to draw a horizontal line that slides up and down in a plot according to the y value of my cursor. In other graphics libraries, you can set the line to draw in xor mode, so if you draw the line once, and then draw it again, the line disappears. Is there a way to do this in matplotlib?

Comment: there is, you'll plot an `axhline`, need to listen for mouse events in your gui backend and set the line's y-value to the current cursor position.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/widgets/cursor.html#sphx-glr-gallery-widgets-cursor-py

Comment: See the [event handling examples](https://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html) of the matplotlib documentation.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as XOR mode. What comes close to this in matplotlib is blitting.

The [`matplotlib.widgets.Cursor`](https://matplotlib.org/api/widgets_api.html#matplotlib.widgets.Cursor) may use this technique in order not to redraw the complete figure, when the line changes.

By default the cursor shows lines in both directions, but you can turn the vertical direction off, `vertOn=False`.

```
from matplotlib.widgets import Cursor
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

cursor = Cursor(ax, vertOn=False, useblit=True, color='red', linewidth=2)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Nice, learned something new again. I would have gone the complicated way using events and updating the line position ...